# Grails and Jasig CAS redirect loop after a few days

Tags: java, tomcat, grails, cas, jasig

Have three Grails applications deployed on the same Tomcat server (tomcat-7.0.54) and after a few (3-4) days, we seem to get stuck in a redirect loop in either one or two of the applications after logging in. One application always seems to be fine, and never have issues. All three have the  same CAS config, copied from one application to the other, with the only differences being the intercept URL maps.

Anyone experienced this, or have any idea where to look? We end up having to restart tomcat in order for the problems to go away, and once we do, all three will be fine for another 3-4 days.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Few days back i also faced this problem, in my situation i just called the url of app1 form my parent application for single sign-on. after successful log-in the app1 is looping. the mistake i did is i just passed the url like "domainname:8080/app1" it will always look for home/index/login page so this looping is happens. i just changed the url like "domainname:8080/app1/login.action", check this it may be useful to you.